# CSS background image transition without resizing

Tags: css, background-image, transition

please take a look [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rVrEQM)

```
transition: background-image 2s;
```

The background images have different sizes and the transition effect is ugly. Is it possible to fade the images without resizing using only CSS ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use two elements, give one the first background, and the other the second background. Position the elements so that one is above the other, and transition the opacity of the element on top.

```js
var current = 0;
setInterval(function() {
    document.querySelector('.image2').style.opacity = (current++ % 2);
}, 3000);
```

```css
.image1,.image2 {
    width: 600px;
    height: 370px;
    border: 1px solid;
    background-color: white;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: contain;
    transition: opacity 2s;
}
.image1 {
    background-image: url('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/61/HTML5_logo_and_wordmark.svg/512px-HTML5_logo_and_wordmark.svg.png');
}
.image2 {
    margin-top: -370px;
    background-image: url('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/83/CSS-Logo.png');
}
```

```html
<div class="image1"></div>
<div class="image2"></div>
```

Or, with [CSS animation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_animations), instead of JavaScript:

```css
@keyframes fade {
  0% { opacity: 0; }
  10% { opacity: 0; }
  40% { opacity: 1; }
  60% { opacity: 1; }
  90% { opacity: 0; }
  100% { opacity: 0; }
}
.image1,.image2 {
    width: 600px;
    height: 370px;
    border: 1px solid;
    background-color: white;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: contain;
}
.image1 {
    background-image: url('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/61/HTML5_logo_and_wordmark.svg/512px-HTML5_logo_and_wordmark.svg.png');
}
.image2 {
    margin-top: -370px;
    background-image: url('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/83/CSS-Logo.png');
    animation: fade 5s linear infinite;
}
```

```html
<div class="image1"></div>
<div class="image2"></div>
```

Comment: I think this is the only solution, but it is using javascript. I can only edit the css file :(

Comment: What about CSS animations?

Comment: @Denni007 Is either of these what you were looking for?